# how to make responsive an absolute div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui

I am making a profile component using material UI and react js,I want to make responsive the Avatar/profile photo and profile name div but I don't know how to do this.Below I am giving some screenshots of my problrm.

The div I want to make responsive is,

[image]

The problem I am facing due to unresponsive,

[image]

My code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import TabPanel from '@mui/lab/TabPanel';
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import TabList from '@mui/lab/TabList';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import '../css/main.css'
// icons

import EmojiEventsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmojiEvents';
import WorkOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/WorkOutline';
import AccountBoxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountBox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import CakeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cake';
import PhoneAndroidIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PhoneAndroid';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import InstagramIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Instagram';
import LinkedInIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LinkedIn';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import SchoolIcon from '@mui/icons-material/School';
import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth';
import ClassIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Class';
import BusinessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Business';
import LocationOnIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocationOn';
import MilitaryTechIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MilitaryTech';

import {
    Box,
    Tab,
    Stack,
    Container,
    Typography,
} from '@mui/material';


function Profile() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Container maxWidth="lg">
                <Stack direction="row" mb={5} >
                    <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                        Profile
                    </Typography>
                </Stack>
                <Stack direction="column" mb={5}>
                    <Box>
                        <Stack sx={{
                            boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px -2px',
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
                        }}>
                            <Box
                                sx={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    height: 250,
                                    backgroundImage: "url('https://api-dev-minimal-v4.vercel.app/assets/images/covers/cover_2.jpg')",
                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                    backgroundPosition: 'center',
                                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 82, 73, 0.8)',
                                    filter: 'blur(4px)',
                                    WebkitFilter: 'blur(4px)',
                                    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
                                    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
                                    zIndex: 9,
                                    // '&:hover': {
                                    //     backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                                    //     opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
                                    // },
                                }}
                            />
                            <Box
                                sx={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    // position: 'absolute',
                                    zIndex: 999,
                                    top: '52%',
                                    backgroundAttachment:'fixed'
                                }}
                            >

                                <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                    <Avatar
                                        alt="Remy Sharp"
                                        src="/assets/images/avatars/avatar_default.jpg"
                                        sx={{
                                            // transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 82, 73, 0.8)',
                                            border: '5px solid #f1f1f1',
                                            boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px -2px',
                                            ml: 5,
                                            width: 140,
                                            height: 140,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Typography
                                        component={Stack}
                                        direction={'column'}
                                        color={'white'}
                                        pt={5}
                                    >
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                textTransform: 'uppercase',
                                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                                fontSize: 26,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Jaydon Frankie
                                        </Box>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                opacity: '0.7'
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Full stack developer
                                        </Box>
                                    </Typography>
                                </Stack>
                            </Box>

                        </Stack>
                    </Box>
                    <TabContext value={value}>
                        <Box
                            pr={2}
                            sx={{
                                width: '100%',
                                borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
                                borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
                                boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px -2px',
                            }}>
                            <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example" ml={'auto'} sx={{
                                float: 'right'
                            }}>
                                <Tab icon={<AccountBoxIcon />} label="Basic Details" value="1" />
                                <Tab icon={<EmojiEventsIcon />} label="Educational Details" value="2" />
                                <Tab icon={<WorkOutlineIcon />} label="Working Details" value="3" />
                            </TabList>
                        </Box>
                        <TabPanel value="1"
                            sx={{ boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px -2px', borderRadius: 3, marginTop: '20px' }}>
                            <Container maxWidth="lg"
                            >
                                <Stack
                                    px={5}
                                    direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'column', md: 'row' }}
                                    width={{ xs: '100%', sm: '100%', md: '100%' }}
                                    spacing={5}>
                                    <Box sx={{
                                        width: '100%',
                                        // boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px'
                                    }}>
                                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                            About
                                        </Typography>
                                        <p>
                                            Tart I love sugar plum I love oat cake. Sweet roll caramels I love jujubes. Topping cake wafer..
                                        </p>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><MailIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography>
                                                    ashlynn_ohara62@gmail.com
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><CakeIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    26/04/1996
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><PhoneAndroidIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    9978542357
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>

                                    </Box>
                                    <Box
                                        sx={{
                                            width: '100%',
                                            // boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px'
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                            Social
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box color={'rgb(24, 119, 242)'}><FacebookIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box
                                                sx={{
                                                    '&:hover': {
                                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Typography >
                                                    https://www.facebook.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box color={'rgb(224, 45, 105)'}><InstagramIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box
                                                sx={{
                                                    '&:hover': {
                                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Typography >
                                                    https://www.instagram.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box color={'rgb(0, 126, 187)'}><LinkedInIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box
                                                sx={{
                                                    '&:hover': {
                                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Typography >
                                                    https://www.linkedin.com/in/caitlyn.kerluke
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box color={'rgb(0, 170, 236)'}><TwitterIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box
                                                sx={{
                                                    '&:hover': {
                                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Typography >
                                                    https://www.twitter.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                    </Box>
                                </Stack>
                            </Container>
                        </TabPanel>
                        <TabPanel value="2"
                            sx={{ boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px -2px', borderRadius: 3, marginTop: '20px' }}>
                            <Container maxWidth="lg"
                            >
                                <Stack
                                    px={5}
                                    direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'column', md: 'row' }}
                                    width={{ xs: '100%', sm: '100%', md: '100%' }}
                                    spacing={5}>
                                    <Box sx={{
                                        width: '100%',
                                        // boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px'
                                    }}>
                                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                            Education
                                        </Typography>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum quae reiciendis, voluptate libero nesciunt iste.
                                            Eum quae reiciendis, voluptate libero nesciunt iste.
                                        </p>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><SchoolIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography>
                                                    St. Paul's Senior Secondary School
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><CalendarMonthIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    2013
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><ClassIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    B.Tech
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>

                                    </Box>
                                </Stack>
                            </Container>
                        </TabPanel>
                        <TabPanel value="3" sx={{ boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px -2px', borderRadius: 3, marginTop: '20px' }}>
                            <Container maxWidth="lg"
                            >
                                <Stack
                                    px={5}
                                    direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'column', md: 'row' }}
                                    width={{ xs: '100%', sm: '100%', md: '100%' }}
                                    spacing={5}>
                                    <Box sx={{
                                        width: '100%',
                                        // boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px'
                                    }}>
                                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                            Work
                                        </Typography>
                                        <p>
                                            Software Engineer at Cybrain Software Solutions Pvt.Ltd .
                                        </p>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><WorkOutlineIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography>
                                                    Cybrain Software Solutions Pvt.Ltd
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><BusinessIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    Private Limited Companies
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><LocationOnIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    Industrial Area, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar,Mohali,Punjab
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                            <Box><MilitaryTechIcon /></Box>
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography >
                                                    Photoshop illustrator HTML CSS
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Stack>

                                    </Box>
                                </Stack>
                            </Container>
                        </TabPanel>
                    </TabContext>
                </Stack>
            </Container>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make immediate parent element as `position: 'relative'` so that absolute div will be stick to that after that maintain space to that absolute `div` as screen break points

eg:

```
      <Stack
          sx={{
            boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px -2px',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            position: 'relative',
          }}
        >  
           ....
       </Stack>
```

Comment: Great happy to hear that !!!